# Can anyone explain me difference on SAX, DOM and XmlPullParser in android

Tags: android

It is very difficult to find out difference among XML parser.
I want to know when to use SAX parser, DOM parser and XmlPullParser.
Explain me with scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

**SAX:**

Parses node by node

Doesnt store the XML in memory

We cant insert or delete a node

Top to bottom traversing

**DOM:**

Stores the entire XML document into memory before processing

Occupies more memory

We can insert or delete nodes

Traverse in any direction.